# MvxRecyclerView ItemDecoration not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-appcompat

I am trying to use MvxRecyclerView. I have directly binded the ItemSource from the ViewModel and its redering the list. But i want the ListItemDivider in between,. So i made a custom ItemDecorator and used it with the recycler view. Its working for andorid 7.0 but not for marshmallow. I m not using any Holder, LinearLayoutManager or Adapter separately for the MvxRecyclerView.Please find the code below

Activity class
//****************************************************************************//

```
[Activity(Label = "EmployeeHub", Theme = "@style/MaterialTheme", ScreenOrientation = AndroidSystem.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class EmployeeHub : BaseView
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EmployeeHub);
        var reclycleView = this.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);
        AndroidSystem.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.ItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this.ApplicationContext);
        reclycleView.AddItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    }
}
```

ItemDecorator 
//********************************************************************//

```
public class DividerItemDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration
{
    private AndroidSystem.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable divider;
    private int[] attributes = new int[] {Attribute.ListDivider };

    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context)
    {
        divider = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.noBorder);
        TypedArray ta = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributes);
        divider = ta.GetDrawable(0);
        ta.Recycle();
    }

    public override void GetItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        if (parent.GetChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        outRect.Top = divider.IntrinsicHeight;
    }

    public override void OnDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        int left = parent.PaddingLeft;
        int right = parent.Width - parent.PaddingRight;

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            View child = parent.GetChildAt(i);

            var parameters = child.LayoutParameters.JavaCast<RecyclerView.LayoutParams>();

            int top = child.Bottom + parameters.BottomMargin;
            int bottom = top + divider.IntrinsicHeight;

            divider.SetBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            divider.Draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

// layout **********************************************//

```
 <MvxRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hlhrview1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/employee_item_template"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Employees; ItemClick SelectedEmployee" />
```

Comment: I don't have time to test this theory right now, but does changing `divider = context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.noBorder);` to `divider = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.noBorder);` make any difference?

Comment: @LukePothier it didn't work..

Comment: Bummer. I think you should add your item template's code and what's inside `BaseView` to your question so it's easier to reproduce.

Comment: Base View is not having any such significant code, it can be replaced with MvxActivity. And ItemTemplate is containing an ImageView and TextView inside a relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a problem getting this to work. With a tip from [here](https://gist.github.com/polbins/e37206fbc444207c0e92#gistcomment-1371417) and a few modifications to your code, I was able to get it working. Specifically, I am using the **OnDrawOver** as opposed to **OnDraw**

Here is my modified DividerItemDecoration:

```
public class DividerItemDecoration : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration
{
    private readonly Drawable _divider;

    public DividerItemDecoration(Context context)
    {

        _divider = ResourcesCompat.GetDrawable(context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.recyclerview_line_divider, context.Theme);
    }

    public override void OnDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        var left = parent.PaddingLeft;
        var right = parent.Width - parent.PaddingRight;

        for (var i = 0; i < parent.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = parent.GetChildAt(i);

            var parameters = child.LayoutParameters.JavaCast<RecyclerView.LayoutParams>();

            var top = child.Bottom + parameters.BottomMargin;
            var bottom = top + _divider.IntrinsicHeight;

            _divider.SetBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            _divider.Draw(c);
        }
    }
}
```

I also put the binding code in my OnCreateView like this:

```
var reclycleView = _payformView.FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.my_recycler_view);
RecyclerView.ItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(Application.Context);
reclycleView.AddItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

All this is on a **KitKat** device.